# cannot create directory for 'local::lib'

Tags: perl

I have installed local::lib from cpan. But the manually one more again to make bootstrap - `perl Makefile.PL −−bootstrap`. And although I have already a file `lib.pm` here `/usr/share/perl5/local/lib.pm`, it when trying to bootstrap it (with the command mentioned above) this error rises:

```
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
Attempting to create directory /home/shepherd/perl5
Unable to create /home/shepherd/perl5/lib/perl5/5.28.0: No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/local/lib.pm line 717.
```

So if I have installed the module, and have it may dir, why the bootstrap cannot create `/home/shepherd/perl5/lib/perl5/5.28.0` ?

```
I have and own this files:
ls -l ~/perl5
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 18 23:03 bin
drwxrwxr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 28 18:52 lib
drwxrwxr-x 4 root root 4096 Oct 28 18:52 man

ls -l ~/perl5/lib
drwxrwxr-x 25 root root 4096 Nov 21 08:56 perl5

ls -l ~perl5/lib/perl5
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 20 19:54 B
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root  4096 Nov 21 08:56 Business
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root  4096 Oct 28 19:08 Class
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 20 19:54 Config
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root  4096 Oct 28 19:09 Devel
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 Oct 28 19:08 Dist
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root  4096 Nov 20 19:54 File
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 20 19:54 Hook
-r--r--r--  1 root root 42537 Feb 18  2018 Importer.pm
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root  4096 Oct 28 19:10 IPC
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root  4096 Nov 18 23:03 Log
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root  4096 Nov 20 20:48 Mac
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root  4096 Oct 28 19:09 MIME
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root  4096 Oct 28 18:52 Module
-r--r--r--  1 root root   967 Sep  6 16:40 ok.pm
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 19 23:13 OLE
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root  4096 Oct 28 19:08 Perl
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root  4096 Oct 28 19:09 POD2
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 Oct 28 19:09 Scope
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 20 19:56 String
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 20 19:54 Task
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root  4096 Oct 28 19:09 Term
drwxrwxr-x  9 root root  4096 Nov 20 19:54 Test
drwxrwxr-x 10 root root  4096 Oct 28 19:09 Test2
-r--r--r--  1 root root  6393 Sep  6 16:40 Test2.pm
drwxrwxr-x  7 root root  4096 Nov 20 19:55 x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
```

Comment: Does any part of the path already exist?

Comment: Does `/home/shepherd/perl5/lib` exist? Do you own it? Do you have read+write+execute permissions to it? Does `/home/shepherd/perl5/lib/perl5` exist? Do you own it? Do you have read+write+execute permissions to it?

Comment: @ikegami yes I do. Both - they exists and I own them.

Comment: According to the listing you added, `root` owns them. But aren't you running as `shepherd`?

Comment: yes the path to dir `/usr/share/perl5/local/lib.pm` does exists. But the output of error:  No such file or directory at `lib/local/lib.pm` line 717. I dont know what that path is the `lib/local/lib.pm` .. is it the same i have mationed? or where does is starts at?

Comment: @ikegami i do, but i am root as well

Comment: "You" meant "The user running the program". Not someone other user, even if you can become that user. It wasn't root that was running the program, so it doesn't matter what permissions root has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

local::lib misreports the error reason. In this particular case, the problem is that the user running the program (`shepherd`) doesn't have permission to write to `/home/shepherd/perl5/lib/perl5` in order to create `/home/shepherd/perl5/lib/perl5/5.28.0`.

The user will need to be granted the ability to write to that directory. This should probably be done by changing the ownership of the files from `root` to `shepherd`.

```
chown -R shepherd:shepherd ~/perl5
```

Comment: Well that sucks, i just made `sudo` for that command and it magically starts working, but how should i have known that before?

Comment: You shouldn't create files a user doesn't own or at least have rights to in their own home directory. You should have known because the downsides of this are rather obvious. Well, if they weren't before, they are now. /// I hope you meant you ran `chown` as root to fix the bad permissions, not `Makefile.PL`.

Comment: I just simpy run it as admin with sudo precommand. Did not change any permissions with chmod, but does it matter?